# Changing the PATH environment variable in Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, php

In my `phpinfo()`, in the section **Apache Environment**, I want to change the value of the variable `PATH`. This is possible? I tried `SetEnv PATH /mypath`, but it does not work. How do I change the PATH variable environment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally familiar, but after having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261971/1440617) to a question over at Stackoverflow, it would seem that the variable you are trying to change isn't actually "set" there.

The author of the answer points out

> The variable is accessible in PHP using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Take a look there.